# Is it possible to store database on local by using TAFFY()

Tags: taffydb

Is it possible to store  database on local by using TAFFY()?

An how to use wild card query on TAFFY()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use db.store() to store in local.
eg:

```
var contact = TAFFY();
contact.store("contact");
```